# после обновления до ubuntu 18.04 слетели горячие клавиши на клавиатуре и переопределились значения клавиш

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Теперь почему-то все печатается транслитом, то есть W=В, I = И, C=Ц и так далее. Ко всему тому же, не получается поменять раскладку на клавиатуре из-за чего я не могу войти в систему. Есть у кого идеи в чем может быть проблема?